# Angle between two connected lines

Tags: geometry, trigonometry

I am a first year physics student, doing some pendulum simulations. The current pendulum I'm trying to simulate follows

[image]

where you have a solid T-bar with three pendulums off each edge of the T-bar. 
All the angles are defined with 0 pointing to the right.

To do the simulation I need to know the potential and kinetic energy of each end of the pendulums. The part I'm having trouble with is the kinetic energy, as that requires me knowing the distance from the edge of a given pendulum to the axis of the T-Bar.

I believe the best way to do this is using the cosine rule, however this requires me to know the angle between an arm of the T-Bar and the corresponding pendulum. The arm has an angle $\theta_t$ defined at the axis of the tbar. The pendulum has an angle $\theta_p$ defined at the point where the pendulum and the arm are connected. I need a function that will accept any $\theta_t$: $0 \le \theta_t \le 2\pi$ and any $\theta_p$: $0 \le \theta_p \le 2\pi$ and will spit out the angle between the arm and the pendulum.

Comment: I don’t quite understand which distances you’re interested in. Are you looking for the distance from each pendulum to its matching colored section of t-bar?

Comment: From the end of each pendulum to the axis, which is where the three coloured parts of the t-bar connect

Answer (score 1):

For the green pendulum, for instance, the angle you need is $\theta_p-\theta_t+\pi/2$, see the diagram below. For the other you may get a slightly different formula, but I think the idea is quite clear.

[image]

Comment: Ahh, hadn't thought of it that way, thanks :D